# How to calculate power of a number in Android SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

How to calculate power of a number in Android SQLite?

I found a [POWER function](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_mathfunc.html#pow) in its documentations,

But it is a part of "Built-In Mathematical SQL Functions" that has some needs:

> The math functions shown below are part of the SQLite amalgamation source file but are only active if the amalgamation is compiled using the -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS compile-time option.

How can I Activate it in Android?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the capabilities of SQLite that is built into Android itself. If that function is not available, your choices are:

- Find an external version of SQLite that used that compiler flag that you can use in your Android app. For example, you could see if [Requery's SQLite](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android) used that compiler flag.
- Live without the function, performing that calculation in Java/Kotlin.